# Identify deviations from trend

Tags: poisson-distribution, panel-data, count-data

I have a panel with individuals $i$ measured at time $t$ (the date). The outcome is a count, which we can call $C$. There's some general time trend $g$ affecting all individuals.

$E[C_{it}] = E[C_{i,t-7}] + g$

That is, conditional on the day of the week, the count is the same in expectation after accounting for the general time trend.

I'd like to identify the person-date pairs for which this equality doesn't hold. In other words, there are some person-dates where an external shock that isn't observed changes the count, and the goal is to identify the date and people to whom that shock occurred. There is no information about how often shocks occurred, and shocks occurring to one person in time $t$ increase the likelihood that shocks occur to someone else in time $t$. Similarly, if person $i$ gets a shock in time $t$, a shock in $t+1$ is more likely.

How would you model this?

Comment: Is it fair to think of the shock-data as outliers? Can we think of this as outlier detection for a time series of counts?